# Will new class instances in Node.js endpoints be garbage collected efficiently?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

New to node.js

I have a long ugly function that builds a CYPHER query for Neo4j. I'd like to convert that into a class, with methods, and a corresponding mocha spec.

Usage would look something like:

```
let matchQuery = new MatchQueryBuilder(user).build()
```

If I use this from within a route/endpoint for a high traffic application, will it be efficiently garbage collected?

Answer (score 1):

As far as there are no more references to an object it **should** be garbage collected. We still don't know **when** it will be deleted.

My personal concern is - javascript garbage collector is rather lazy one, but as far as **memory consume** raises - he does his job.

Route - is just a function, as far as it is executed - all automatic variables are deleted.